# LEFT - JOIN and WHERE is not working as expected in query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 tables: residual_types, containers, collections and collection_container. Each container has a residual_type and there is many-to-many relationship between containers and collections.

I need to make query that, in a given day, tells me how much mass has been collected for each residual_type, even though there is not any record associated with the residual_type. For example, in a given day, the "ORGANIC" residual_types has 850 kg collected, it shows "ORGANIC | 850", but if it had 0 kg collected, it would show "ORGANIC | 0".

This is the query I am using, but it seems that it does not respect the WHERE clause for collections.creation_time and it brings all the records

```
SELECT residual_types.name AS name, IFNULL(SUM(collection_container.mass),0) AS mass
FROM residual_types
INNER JOIN containers ON containers.residual_type_id = residual_types.id
INNER JOIN collection_container ON collection_container.container_id = containers.id
LEFT JOIN collections ON collection_container.collection_id = collections.id AND collections.creation_time BETWEEN 1557637200 AND 1557723599
GROUP BY residual_types.id
ORDER BY mass DESC

+---------+------+
| name    | mass |
+---------+------+
| organic | 7580 |
+---------+------+
| paper   | 1243 |
+---------+------+
| plastic | 123  |
+---------+------+
```

I've also tried this query, but it does not bring any records.

```
SELECT residual_types.name AS name, IFNULL(SUM(collection_container.mass),0) AS mass
FROM residual_types
INNER JOIN containers ON containers.residual_type_id = residual_types.id
INNER JOIN collection_container ON collection_container.container_id = containers.id
INNER JOIN collections ON collection_container.collection_id = collections.id
WHERE collections.creation_time BETWEEN 1557637200 AND 1557723599
GROUP BY residual_types.id
ORDER BY mass DESC
```

If there are not any collections associated with the residual_type, then the result set should look like this:

```
+---------+------+
| name    | mass |
+---------+------+
| organic | 0    |
+---------+------+
| paper   | 0    |
+---------+------+
| plastic | 0    |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your observation. What query would you suggest for my problem?

Comment: @NoChance every column in the part of the query that you posted is different.

Comment: What column type is `creation_time`?

Comment: Your first query does not have a where clause, and isn't that the main point of your question?

Comment: @Nick creation_time is a BIGINT(20) and it represents a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @GianMS the values you are comparing `creation_time` with are not unix timestamps, they include milliseconds as well. Perhaps you need to divide `1557637200000` by `1000`?

Comment: Your second query should work only change you need to do is as suggested by Nick, divide your time range by 1000

Comment: @Nick I updated the question. Time is in seconds now.

Comment: With that change does your second query still bring no records?

Comment: @Nick Indeed, it brings no records.

Comment: Just updated the question with some examples.

Comment: As an attempt to debug this why not add collections.creation_time to the select clause and the group by and see what you get, You could also add sample data from all your tables as text to the question together with table definitions.AND why are you ordering by weight when looking at mass?

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Please don't give multiple wrong queries. Ask about the problem with the first subexpression you added that doesn't return what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the value you are summing will always be a number, regardless of whether there was a collection or not. You need to condition the sum with whether there was a collection or not, which you can do by changing that expression from

```
IFNULL(SUM(collection_container.mass), 0)
```

to

```
SUM(CASE WHEN collections.id IS NOT NULL THEN collection_container.mass ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patient. Your solution works. I guess I can go to sleep now. Thank you, you're the best.

Comment: @GianMS no worries. I think we all spent too much time focusing on the wrong thing. It was only when you put the sample data in that I went back and looked at what you were summing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is int the design in that the mass is held in collection_container. I would have expected it in collections. The effect is that the mass is found before the left join (which fails on date).

For example

```
drop table if exists residual_types,containers,collection_container,collections;
create table residual_types(id int,name varchar(3));
create table containers(id int,residual_type_id int);
create table collection_container(container_id int,collection_id int,mass int);
create table collections(id int,creation_time bigint);

insert into residual_types values(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc');
insert into containers values(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1);
insert into collection_container values(1,10,100),(1,20,100),(1,30,100);
insert into collections values(10,1557637100),(20,1557637200),(30,1557723599);



SELECT residual_types.name AS name, collections.creation_time, 
         IFNULL(SUM(collection_container.mass),0) AS mass
FROM residual_types
INNER JOIN containers ON containers.residual_type_id = residual_types.id
INNER JOIN collection_container ON collection_container.container_id = containers.id
LEFT JOIN collections ON collection_container.collection_id = collections.id AND collections.creation_time BETWEEN 1557637200 AND 1557723599
GROUP BY residual_types.id,collections.creation_time
ORDER BY mass DESC;

+------+---------------+------+
| name | creation_time | mass |
+------+---------------+------+
| aaa  |          NULL |  100 |
| aaa  |    1557637200 |  100 |
| aaa  |    1557723599 |  100 |
+------+---------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```